Conditional execution of `tar_target` with dynamic branching
I have an R workflow built using targets. The process retrieves thousand of weather station data and carry out some statistical analysis. Depending on the analysis results, I'd like to "fix" the weather data.
Since I have many stations, I'm using dynamic branching to retrieve the data and carry on the stats analysis. I then would like to identify if there are any problematic stations and fix them (using branching).
If I have a vector with the problematic stations, I can do the branching. But what no stations are identified as problematic? How do I skip this target? I tried using tarchetypes::tar_skip but it appears it's not able to do branching.
Here goes a shot at a reprex:
library(targets)

data <- data.frame(
  id = rep(1:3, each = 10),
  val = runif(30)
)

correct <- function(data) {
  data$val <- data$val * 10
  return(data)
}

list(
  tar_target(
    ids,
    1:3
  ),
  tar_target(
    station_data,
    data[data$id == ids,],
    pattern = ids
  ),
  tar_target(
    bad_stations,
    ids[2:3]
  ),
  tar_target(
    corrected_data,
    correct(data[data$id == bad_stations,]),
    pattern = bad_stations
  ),
  ## what if there are no bad stations?
  tar_target(
    bad_stations2,
    ids[0]
  ),
  # this gives the following error
  # Error:
  #   ! Error running targets::tar_make()
  # Error messages: targets::tar_meta(fields = error, complete_only = TRUE)
  # Debugging guide: https://books.ropensci.org/targets/debugging.html
  # How to ask for help: https://books.ropensci.org/targets/help.html
  # Last error: cannot branch over empty target (bad_stations2)
  tar_target(
    corrected_data2,
    correct(data[data$id == bad_stations2,]),
    pattern = bad_stations2
  )
)


Meanwhile, I "solved" it by creating a function that will process a weather station data and do something different depending if it's in the bad_station list or not.
